# Is there a way to make text resize if I change browser zoom while using viewport unit

Tags: css, viewport-units

I choose to work with viewport units to make my web application responsive.

The problem is when I set the font size in `vw`, I get exactly the size that I want for all screens, but when I change the browser zoom, the text still has the same size.

I tried a way but I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

My actual solution is to combine pixels with `vw` using `calc`

```
text: {
  fontSize: 'calc(10px + 2vw)'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From 
https://css-tricks.com/books/volume-i/scale-typography-screen-size/
They have a nice formula i used

```
  font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

Example:

```
  font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
```

That means it will have FontSize of 14px on 300px screens and an font-size of 26px on screens with 1600px width.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problème, if you try to increase the browser zoom, the font will always have the same size